# Retrieve excel row value by checking if value within range of 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any idea for an excel formula that should accept an input and return the value of the **relevant row** in *Price*  column if the value entered is greater than the *LowerRange* column but lower than the *UpperRange* column.

i.e. input of 6 would return 5, input of 18 would return 10, input of 52 would return 30.

```
LowerRange  UpperRange  Price
1           10          5 
11          20          10
21          30          15
31          40          20
41          50          25
51          60          30

InputCell:
InputFormula:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])` with `range_lookup` set to `TRUE`

From Excel help file:

> > > If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.
> > >
> > > If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, the values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP might not return the correct value.

So, for your data use `=VLOOKUP(B10,$A$2:$C$8,3,1)` where value to look up is in `B10` (add a value of 61 to col A and =NA() to col C to the end of the data to handle inputs > 60)